# Is it true that the intersection of the closure of span is a subset of the closure of span of intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let V be a Banach space

Let $\{B_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of subsets of $V$

My question is if the intersection of the closure of span $B_n$ is the closure of span of intersection $B_n$, that is
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty
\overline
{
\operatorname{span} B_n
}
\subset
\overline
{
\operatorname{span} 
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n
}
$$
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general. It can for example happen that the spans are dense, but have trivial intersection. Consider $V = \ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ for some $p \in [1, +\infty)$, and

$$B_1 = \{e_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\},\quad B_2 = \{ e_n + f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

where $e_n$ is the standard unit sequence ($e_n(k) = \delta_{nk}$) and $f_n(k) = 2^{-(n+1)k}$. Then every element of $\operatorname{span} B_1$ has only finitely many nonzero terms, but every nonzero element of $\operatorname{span} B_2$ has infinitely many nonzero terms. But both spans are dense in $V$.

We have the inclusion in the other direction,

$$\overline{\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} \operatorname{span} B_n} \subset \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} \overline{\operatorname{span} B_n},$$

however.

Comment: Thanks so much @Daniel Fischer for your answer